# Shrink margins by reducing paper size

Tags: margins, paper-size

Often we are forced to write our manuscripts with a specific style file or document class, which sometimes has ridiculously large margins. Is there an easy way to work out how to shrink the paper size at the expense of reducing the margins? That is, achieve the same effect as taking a pair of scissors trimming the margins down.

Smaller margins would be nice when preparing the manuscript as it allows me to have the preview zoomed in without cropping the page. It is important that the layout of the text remains fixed; text width and page breaks have to be identical to the version with the original margins.

Comment: look at the `geometry` package which has lots of facilities for setting page and margin dimensions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You could say that this is the question I have: how do I use the geometry package to shrink the paper size without affecting the text flow (text width, page breaks, etc). I want to emulate someone taking a pair of scissors, cutting off large parts of the margins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `pdflatex` is used, this can be done in a quick and dirty way by setting `\pdf<h|v>origin` and `\pdfpage<width|height>`. Example that reduces the margins by `1in`:

```
\documentclass{...}
% normal papersize settings

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pdfhorigin=\dimexpr\pdfhorigin-1in\relax
  \pdfvorigin=\dimexpr\pdfvorigin-1in\relax
  \pdfpagewidth=\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-2in\relax
  \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\pdfpageheight-2in\relax
}%

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This "quick and dirty way" seems to do the job for me. I wanted to be able to do this for so long.